# Undefined index: action on codeigniter with get

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter

i'm using a installing a javascript chat on my website.
It seems i get "Undefined index: action" on my website that is using Codeigniter, but it is working fine on a normal website using standard php.
The error comes from this:

```
if($_GET['action'] == "chatheartbeat") { chatHeartbeat(); } 
if($_GET['action'] == "sendchat") { sendChat(); } 
if($_GET['action'] == "closechat") { closeChat(); } 
if($_GET['action'] == "startchatsession") { startChatSession(); }
```

Is there anyway i can make this work?
I have been trying everything i could, even google'd it without success.

I'm sure that the reason for the `$_GET` is because it is a full JavaScript chat.

Answer (score 0):

The reason the error is being thrown is because somehow that piece of code is not getting that action value, the reason the website is not throwing that error is probably because the php.ini that the website uses has errors turned off. If that is the case, then the error is still there just not being shown. I hope this information is helpful in you finding the error, other than that I am not familiar with Codeigniter, so if it's something to do with Codeigniter I wouldn't know.